# Django 1.10 Showing link in HTML if date > field from table

Tags: django-templates, django-views

I can't get it done. I want to show a link, only if the systemdate passed the date from a record. How do I do this the best way? i tried it within html with:

```
{% if dienst.startvc <= {% now %} %}
    <h4><br/><u><a href="/planning/urenstaat/{{dienst.id}}">Urenstaat</a></u></h4>
{% endif %}
```

But that doesn't work.

Then I tried it different from within the view and then using two different html-pages. Not logical but okay, I had to try. But even that didn't work:

```
class DienstDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):  
    model = Dienst  
    if Dienst.startvc <= datetime.now():   
        template_name = "planning/dienst_detail_nacalc.html"   
    else:   
        template_name = "planning/dienst_detail.html"
```

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need {% %} around now in your template

`{% if dienst.startvc <= now %}`

Comment: Great. That's it. I only had to put formats to the fields and then it worked. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date you can used template tag date to display a date with a specific format.
Do not hesitate to accept the answer if this has solved your problem.